# How to interpret NDK unwind

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an application that includes a major amount of native C++ code. Lately I've been seeing a crash that has been quite hard to track. I use NDK unwind to generate stacktraces when a crash occurs. These stacktraces have been quite consistently clear, but for this peculiar case the stacktrace is rather puzzling:

```
************************************************ 
Signal Caught: Segmentation fault, at time: 06/07/2020 14:58:36.205 

000: 0x95924d94 dump_stack(int)

001: 0x832a722e  

002: 0xb2079968  

003: 0xa79b72dc vixl::aarch32::Assembler::BindHelper(vixl::aarch32::Label*) 

004: 0xa78f75f0  

005: 0xa7832eee art::CodeGenerator::GenerateSlowPaths() 

006: 0xa783314a art::CodeGenerator::Compile(art::CodeAllocator*) 

007: 0xa788663c art::OptimizingCompiler::TryCompile(art::ArenaAllocator*, art::CodeVectorAllocator*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, unsigned int, art::InvokeType, unsigned short, unsigned int, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>, art::DexFile const&, art::Handle<art::mirror::DexCache>, art::ArtMethod*, bool, art::VariableSizedHandleScope*) const 

008: 0xa7887b1c art::OptimizingCompiler::JitCompile(art::Thread*, art::jit::JitCodeCache*, art::ArtMethod*, bool, art::jit::JitLogger*) 

009: 0xa7825462 art::jit::JitCompiler::CompileMethod(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, bool) 

010: 0xae87e08e art::jit::Jit::CompileMethod(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, bool) 

011: 0xae87fe06  

012: 0xae9a7caa art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run() 

013: 0xae9a78da art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)

014: 0xb20a85c0  

015: 0xb207bf36  
************************************************
```

I'm unable to find much information about any of the function calls in this stack. I'm assuming it's part of some internal system, but I cant seem to figure out exactly what is going on.Does this type of stack trace indicate any specific problem? I'm mostly seeing it shortly after making a `startActivity()` call, if that is any help.

Comment: Hint: [rr](https://rr-project.org/) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

This stack trace is indeed something internal - it's in the Android RunTime (ART) itself. Likely wasn't your fault. Let's step through (since this is a stack trace, in reverse order):

```
013: 0xae9a78da art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)
012: 0xae9a7caa art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run() 

  ART creates a thread pool for JIT compilers. This means that there is a small number of pre-allocated threads, which may pick up work as needed. They block, until triggered.


011: 0xae87fe06  
010: 0xae87e08e art::jit::Jit::CompileMethod(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, bool) 
009: 0xa7825462 art::jit::JitCompiler::CompileMethod(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, bool)
```

The thread woke up, and started the process of Just-In-Time (JIT) compiling a method.

```
008: 0xa7887b1c art::OptimizingCompiler::JitCompile(art::Thread*, art::jit::JitCodeCache*, art::ArtMethod*, bool, art::jit::JitLogger*) 
007: 0xa788663c art::OptimizingCompiler::TryCompile(art::ArenaAllocator*, art::CodeVectorAllocator*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, unsigned int, art::InvokeType, unsigned short, unsigned int, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>, art::DexFile const&, art::Handle<art::mirror::DexCache>, art::ArtMethod*, bool, art::VariableSizedHandleScope*) const
```

The JIT compiler goes and attempts to actually perform the compilation..

```
006: 0xa783314a art::CodeGenerator::Compile(art::CodeAllocator*)
```

.. Handing it to the Code Generator. This selects one of several potential backends (in practice, only the Optimizing compiler)

```
005: 0xa7832eee art::CodeGenerator::GenerateSlowPaths()
```

which hits a "slow path" (i.e. one that isn't cached or can't be quickly computed with a lookup table or such)

```
004: 0xa78f75f0  
003: 0xa79b72dc vixl::aarch32::Assembler::BindHelper(vixl::aarch32::Label*)
```

and then fails in LibVixl. That's the project (by Linaro, I believe) which is used as ART's (here) assembler and disassembler.

```
002: 0xb2079968  
001: 0x832a722e  
000: 0x95924d94 dump_stack(int)
```

Segmentation fault occurs. Stack is dumped.

So, not your fault - a bug internal to ART, libvixl or somewhere in their interface. This was probably fixed a long time ago (old question) - But definitely worth an answer since this is, as you correctly say, without much information/documentation about it.